# Python: Tuple List from File

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two txt file, each file contain a tuple list:

A file contains a tuple list where each element is composed by an integer and a floating number:

```
(22, 0.4271125909116274) 
(14, 0.4212051728881959) 
(3, 0.4144765342960289) 
....
```

The other file contains a tuple list where each element is composed by two integers:

```
(22, 82276) 
(14, 80125) 
(38, 79598) 
....
```

I want to give those lists as inputs to a function, can someone suggest me a way to import those two lists from files?

Comment: 1. Open the File. 2. Read the contents 3. Parse the Input - You can find the floats v/s int using `isinstance`

Comment: A tuple is not a list.

Comment: @ap She/he wrotes tuple list which should mean list of tuples I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are basically asking "How to open a file in python?"

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        your_func(line) # this will be each line in the `filename`
```

If you are opening a file with `with`, you don't have to close the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as ins:
    tuples = []
    for line in ins:
        tuples.append(tuple(line[1:-1].split(', ')))
```

This will open your file, parse it (takes the part between brackets and split it in a 2 element list), next it converts it to a tuple and adds it to a list of tuples.

this can be further enhanced by list comprehension, but for simplicity reasons I won't go into that.

Answer (score 0):

Using eval could be one solution:

```
# say file is a.txt
mylist = []

with open('a.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        mylist.append(eval(line))

print(mylist)
```

Note:- With that said, eval should be used judiciously.

Comment: It's per-fect! Thx so much ^^

Comment: If it was helpful, please mark it as correct answer